# OpenFOAM9 "error while loading shared libraries"

Tags: ubuntu, cluster-computing, openmpi, openfoam

**Background info:**

runAirfoil2D.sh

```
echo "Running simulation with $numberOfSubdomains processes."

executable=/opt/openfoam9/platforms/linux64GccDPInt32Opt/bin/simpleFoam

mpirun --hostfile $machines -np $numberOfSubdomains --display-allocation $executable -parallel
```

Terminal error message:

```
mpiuser@master:$FOAM_RUN/tutorials/incompressible/simpleFoam$ ./runAirfoil2D.sh
Running simulation with 8 processes.

ALLOCATED NODES   ======================
master: flags=0x11 slots=4 max_slots=0 slots_inuse=0 state=UP
acl-n1: flags=0x13 slots=4 max_slots=0 slots_inuse=0 state=UNKNOWN
# =================================================================
# /opt/openfoam9/platforms/linux64GccDPInt32Opt/bin/simpleFoam: error while loading shared libraries: libmomentumTransportModels.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
# /opt/openfoam9/platforms/linux64GccDPInt32Opt/bin/simpleFoam: error while loading shared libraries: libmomentumTransportModels.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
# /opt/openfoam9/platforms/linux64GccDPInt32Opt/bin/simpleFoam: error while loading shared libraries: libmomentumTransportModels.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
# /opt/openfoam9/platforms/linux64GccDPInt32Opt/bin/simpleFoam: error while loading shared libraries: libmomentumTransportModels.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------
Primary job  terminated normally, but 1 process returned
a non-zero exit code. Per user-direction, the job has been aborted.
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun detected that one or more processes exited with non-zero status, thus causing
the job to be terminated. The first process to do so was:

Process name: [[434,1],4]
Exit code:    127
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I am putting together a cluster for my professor. There are 20 computers with 4 cores each, but I'm only working on the master and the first node right now.

It seems whenever I run simpleFoam with 4 subdomains it runs ok because it's just running on the master computer's 4 cores. But when I try to incorporate the first node (so 8 subdomains) it throws errors saying it can't find a shared object file, even though it is there:

```
mpiuser@master:$FOAM_RUN/tutorials/incompressible/simpleFoam$ ldd /opt/openfoam9/platforms/linux64GccDPInt32Opt/bin/simpleFoam
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe7bd25000)
libmomentumTransportModels.so => /opt/openfoam9/platforms/linux64GccDPInt32Opt/lib/libmomentumTransportModels.so (0x00007f18b8600000)

and so on....
```

I have a hello world script that works using openMPI and NFS so I know my connections and mounts are correct.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Is it seen in the child node?